# How can I set project folders to distinct colors in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How can I set project folders to distinct colors and the files tabs take that color as a background in WebStorm & IntelliJ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Define custom Scope(s) that will include desired files/folders at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes`

   https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-scopes.html
2. Apply settings (so the scopes are saved)
3. Create entries at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | File Colors` -- one entry per scope and associate it with a desired color.

   Make sure that the appropriate checkboxes are selected (where to use those colors)

   https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html

   NOTE: colors applied from top to the bottom: first match will get the color.

[image]

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, however how can I change the background color of the opened tab. it's in Purple now.

Comment: Show a screenshot of how it looks (should show the same file in the Project View panel as well) -- maybe it will give some hints as I need to see what "background" you mean. Ideally using Default light (IntelliJ Light) or Darcula themes (as I'm more familiar with them). Right now it can be 1) your current GUI Theme. 2) Custom plugin (there is one to change active tab color AFAIK), or some Material Theme UI. 3) Maybe something else .. but need to see the screenshot first.

Comment: Yes thank you, I was experimenting with plugins and one of them was responsible for the purple color. I removed it and now it's back to normal. just curious do you work for jetbrains or you just know their products well. Thanks again for all your help.